# API call on event in react, componentDidUpdate or eventHandler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, asynchronous, react-lifecycle

Where should we ideally place an api call to be made on occurrence of an event in React

Inside the `eventHandler` or `componentDidUpdate` ?

example:

```
handleItemClick = (item) => (event) => {
  this.setState({selectedItem: item});
  this.props.requestDataActionDispatch(item);
}
```

OR

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if(prevState.item !== this.state.item) {
    this.props.requestDataActionDispatch(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to wait for component update, I'd just put it in the event handler.

Naturally, in either case your component needs to know how to render appropriately when it has a selected item but doesn't have the data from the API yet...

---

(Side note: **If** `requestDataActionDispatch` results in a state change in your component, you probably want to clear that state when setting the selected item prior to the request, so you don't have one item selected but still have the state related to the previous item. But I'm guessing from the fact it's on `props` that it doesn't...)

Answer (score 1):

**Depends**

But a simple solution is, if you want to call some API after change of state value then you must go for `eventHandler`. Also check for [`callback`](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) in `setState`.

```
handleItemClick = (item) => (event) => {
  this.setState({selectedItem: item}, () => this.props.requestData(item));
}
```

Comment: Not seeing any particular need to wait for the state update before firing off the data request.

Answer (score 0):

#### It depends

I would prefer to call the api inside `componentDidUpdate`. Why ? Because it's cleaner. Whenever there is a change in state or props, `componentDidUpdate` will be called. So definitely, there has to be a condition inside `componentDidUpdate` like you have mentioned

```
if(prevState.item !== this.state.item)
```