# Dispatch same action in event handler AND in ComponentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

recently I was learning the `Redux` + `Redux thunk` to deal with async actions. In the `official tutorial about the Reddit API`, I don't quite understand that why we need to dispatch `fetchPostsIfNeeded`(means fetch the posts if needed) multiple time.The Link is [Official](https://redux.js.org/advanced/example-reddit-api), and the online editor's [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/72j28q2k50).

In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769875/api-call-on-event-in-react-componentdidupdate-or-eventhandler) on StackOverflow, they've had discussion about this, but they only chose to use either `event handler` or `componentDidUpdate`, not using both the same time.

The **Question** is: in the official example, is it **redundant** to handle the dispatch action in `componentDidUpdate`(*to fetch posts if update available*) if there is already a `handleChange` and `handleRefreshClick` (*to fetch posts if update available*) in there ? I have attached the `React life cycle` here for better understanding.

[image: Life Cycle in React]

*Code snippets* for file `AsyncApp.js`:

```
class AsyncApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleRefreshClick = this.handleRefreshClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (this.props.selectedSubreddit !== prevProps.selectedSubreddit) {
      const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
      dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    }
  }

  handleChange(nextSubreddit) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    this.props.dispatch(selectSubreddit(nextSubreddit))
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(nextSubreddit))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }

  handleRefreshClick(e) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    e.preventDefault()

    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(invalidateSubreddit(selectedSubreddit))
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedSubreddit, posts, isFetching, lastUpdated } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Picker
          value={selectedSubreddit}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={['reactjs', 'frontend']}
        />
        <p>
          {lastUpdated && (
            <span>
              Last updated at {new Date(lastUpdated).toLocaleTimeString()}.{' '}
            </span>
          )}
          {!isFetching && (
            <button onClick={this.handleRefreshClick}>Refresh</button>
          )}
        </p>
        {isFetching && posts.length === 0 && <h2>Loading...</h2>}
        {!isFetching && posts.length === 0 && <h2>Empty.</h2>}
        {posts.length > 0 && (
          <div style={{ opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1 }}>
            <Posts posts={posts} />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { selectedSubreddit, postsBySubreddit } = state
  const { isFetching, lastUpdated, items: posts } = postsBySubreddit[
    selectedSubreddit
  ] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }

  return {
    selectedSubreddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AsyncApp)
```

Thank you

Comment: doing so from `componentDidUpdate` is for the use case where any of your props changes. In the code example, that'd be when `selectedSubreddit` changes. Doing it from the button is for another use case: A manual even handler, triggered by the user. You should implement one, another, or both, according to your needs. So, basically: _it depends_

Comment: I understand, but, let's say, i `manually` clicked a button, then it will fetch the posts, then, the `componentDidUpdate` monitored the change,  will it fetch again ? is this duplicate, thank you

Comment: yes, if your prop changed. The condition in componentDidUpdate is independent from what you've done in your click.

Comment: @Gonzalo.-Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this exact sample `componentDidUpdate` is useless, as requests to update are made from inside event handler. But if you have additional component, say `ThirdPartyUpdater` which will present `Picker` somewhere in another place in SPA, `componentDidUpdate` will do it job to refetch posts.

I've modified [provided demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reddit-api-react-redux-03qth) to showcase this. Upper Picker is separate component from `AsyncApp` and it just update `selectedSubreddit`. `AsyncApp` then receives updated props and request new subreddit in `componentDidUpdate`.

From my point of view, it's better to put `fetchPostsIfNeeded` inside `selectSubreddit` action creator. Whenever we select new subreddit, we should immediately refetch posts. So separating these two steps may create bugs in future.